# Joining tables inflates number values

Tags: sql

Here is my query, I have different account values (the `accValByProd` table) that I want to add to my table by their product type. If I just select the `accValByProd` table by itself the numbers are accurate, but when I join it with the billing table the numbers become much larger than they should be.

As you can see since I need to take the MAX of values in the billing table and then SUM them in the final calculation, I can't just do that in the final SELECT (unless there's a way to do that?). Any help is appreciated I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
WITH billing AS
(   SELECT 
            bh.debit_account_id,
            bh.period_start_date,
            bh.period_end_date,
            bh.a_id,
            bh.account_value,
            bh.platform_fee
        FROM 
            billing_history bh
        WHERE 
                -- LESS than same day following year includes any 
                -- possible time portion if so part of.
                bh.period_start_date >= '2020-07-01'
            and bh.period_end_date < '2021-07-01'
            and bh.a_fee != 0
), 
acc_prods AS
(
SELECT 
        a.account_id,
        a.product_id,
        CASE WHEN p.product_type = 3 THEN 'FSP'
             WHEN p.product_type = 6 THEN 'APM'
             WHEN p.product_type = 13 THEN 'UMA'                                                                         
             ELSE 'Unknown' END product_type,
        a.a_id
    FROM 
        account a
            LEFT JOIN product p
                ON a.product_id = p.product_id
    WHERE 
            -- which table alias, should never leave blind
            -- assumption here is "Account" table (alias a)
            a.close_date IS NULL 
        OR  a.close_date >= GETDATE()
), 
accounts AS (                                                    
SELECT 
        a.account_id,
        a.a_id,
        a.customer_id,
        a.close_date
    FROM 
        account a
), 
accValByProd as 
(
SELECT 
        bh.debit_account_id AS deb_id,
        bh.period_end_date,
        MAX(bh.account_value) AS acc_val,
        bh.a_id,
        ISNULL(ap.product_type, 'Unknown') AS prod_type                                     
    FROM 
        billing_history bh
            LEFT JOIN acc_prods ap
                ON bh.debit_account_id = ap.account_id
    WHERE
        bh.period_end_date = '2021-06-30'
    GROUP BY 
        bh.debit_account_id, 
        bh.period_end_date, 
        bh.a_id, 
        ap.product_type
)
                                                    
SELECT DISTINCT 
        ad.ad_id, 
        ad.fname + ' ' + ad.middle + ' ' + ad.lname 'full name',
        accValByProd.prod_type AS 'product type', 
        COUNT(DISTINCT billing.debit_account_id) AS 'number of accounts', 
        SUM(accValByProd.acc_val) AS 'product aum',
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, billing.period_start_date, billing.period_end_date) > 31 
                THEN billing.platform_fee ELSE 0 END) AS 'fees'
    FROM 
        advisor ad
            JOIN billing 
                ON ad.a_id = billing.a_id
                JOIN accounts 
                    ON billing.debit_account_id = accounts.account_id
                JOIN accValByProd 
                    ON billing.debit_account_id = accValByProd.deb_id
    WHERE 
            1=1 
        and (   ad.termination_date IS NULL 
            OR ad.termination_date >= GETDATE()) 
        AND (   accounts.close_date IS NULL 
            OR accounts.close_date >= '2021-06-30')
    GROUP BY 
        ad.a_id, 
        ad.fname,
        ad.middle,
        ad.lname, 
        accValByProd.prod_type
```

Here are the expected results for a_id 6835 (plus the other information)

```
a_id  product aum   product type
----  ------------  -------------
6835  7861895.23    APM
6835  47059722.64   FSP
6835  9816992.32    UMA
6835  528930.47     Unknown
```

And here are the actual results:

```
a_id  product aum   product type
----  ------------  -------------
6835  45447953.20   APM 
6835  203942000.07  FSP
6835  77678383.30   UMA
6835  1706276.86    Unknown
```

Comment: Could you please give an example as table's snippet and related expected result?

Comment: Yes I will add that now

Comment: I haven't examined your query, but I suspect that you are joining table rows that you should not join. A typical example is a forum with a likes and a dislikes table. You want to count likes and dislikes per post, but you must not join the likes and dislikes, but the like sums and the dislike sums. That means: aggregate first, then join.  Hope this helps.

Comment: So that seemed to fix the issue but now my 'number of accounts' column all shows the same number. It looks to be the total of all the different product types rather than each individually

Comment: Simplify! [mcve]